# How can I change plugin installation path in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I've reinstalled my Windows lately, but IntelliJ was on another drive and was left as-is. It works just fine, but it wouldn't allow me to install any sort of plug-ins, outputting the error after asking to restart it:

> The cause: java.nio.file.FileSystemException:
> G:\jet_brains\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\231.8109.175.plugins: Unable to
> determine if root directory exists

I tried to set a new plugin installation path in *idea.properties*, but it failed:

> idea.plugins.path =
> "E:\programming\_tools\jetbrains\plugins\intellij"

The funny thing is, to my knowledge, the mentioned G drive in the error message never even existed on my PC. What could be the cause of this strange behavior and how could I amend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install a new copy of IDE, and use the menu File > Manage IDE Settings > Import Settings to import settings from the old IDE directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't change anything

Comment: I suggest installing a new copy of IDE, and using the menu File > Manage IDE Settings > Import Settings to import settings from the old IDE directory.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you please post it as an answer, so I could mark it as a solution?

Comment: You are welcome, I've updated the original content, please mark it as a solution.